# bash: patch.exe: Permission denied; how to turn off security regarding 'patch' in program name in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bash, security, permissions, cygwin

I stumbled upon a problem patching a [.diff](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/diffutils/) file using [patch](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/patch/). I use bash under windows 10 and the result of of this operation is as follows:

```
$ patch < patch.diff
bash: /cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/patch: Permission denied
```

I checked the file, it was untouched (compared with backup archive), it was mine and had read and executable permissions. Nothing helped.
And then I tried to run it as admin and it worked.
All other programs have no problem only this one. Simple utility that cannot work without administrative permissions.

Then I got enlightened - it was a name, `patch` name. I renamed it to `pat` and it worked like a charm. So I tried to add a number or some random letters (like `patch1`, `qwepatchrty`), but the result was the same - permission denied. I have never seen something such stupid but here you have it - if you put a word `patch` in executable name you will not be able to run it without administrative privileges.

You can get any [hello world program](https://github.com/pts/pts-tinype/blob/master/hh3wf.golden.exe), rename it `patch.exe` and get same result: `permission denied`!. For those who don't get it:

```
$ wget -Ohello.exe https://github.com/pts/pts-tinype/raw/master/hh3wf.golden.exe
$ cp hello.exe patch.exe
$ ./patch.exe
bash: ./patch.exe: Permission denied
$ ./hello.exe
Hello, World!
```

I tried to add exclusion in windows defender, and it didn't work. I ran out of ideas and steam with such a genius security measure.

I even tried to add manifest to this, or any other program for that matter, as I found some [discusion on cygwin forum](https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/cygwin/2009-03/msg00010.html), but it didn't help either.

Any idea how to turn off this 'ingenious' security measure as it's incomprehensibly stunning?

Comment: What are the permissions on the file that is at this location: /cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/patch ?  Specifically, is it executable?

Comment: As said, it's executable, it's mine (I am the owner), it has read and execute permissions. But this is not the case. Even if I give it all the permissions, literally all of them it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: I put a bit of research into the problem, and while I found a few links, they are pretty much along the lines you've already worked out.  Windows treats programs with "patch" "update" and "install" or words like them in the name specially, for "reasons".  If you respect that, and try to work with Windows, I suspect your efforts will be more fruitful, but I too think it is a bit of a crude hack on Microsoft's part.

Comment: So,, how can I turn it off? I have an ID so I'm big enough to know what I do. I don't have to be treated like a child.

Comment: I don't know, and I don't know if it can be turned off; that's more knowledge than I (or apparently you) have, and maybe that should be part of the question.  Best of luck in your future endeavors.

Comment: It is in the question (_how to turn off security guard..._)